# Quantidade de consultas realizadas NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, express.js

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma para pegar o numero de requisições feitas para um servidor nodejs desde o ultimo restart.

Por exemplo:

- Admin: node index.js
- User: 127.0.0.1:3000/all
- User2: 127.0.0.1:3000/all
- User3: 127.0.0.1:3000/all

x = 3 (numero de requisições feitas desde o ultimo restart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie um `middleware` para realizar a contagem:

```
const contador = 0;

const adicionar = async (req, res, next) => {
  contador += 1;
  next();
};

const contar = () => {
  return contador;
};

module.exports = {
  adicionar,
  contar,
};
```

No local onde você inicializa suas rotas:

```
const { adicionar, contar } = require('./middleware');

// ...
app.use(adicionar);
```

E para saber quantas requisições foram feitas utilize a função `contar`.